# How can I keep old value selected option on edit request in VueJS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some records with relationships on db. I fetch them on laravel backend like this

```
$teams = Team::with('skills')->find($id);

        return response()->json([
            'teams' =>$teams,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
```

and on front i am using vue js to edit team record

```
editTeam(id) {
                axios.get('/teams/'+id+'/edit')
                .then(response => {
                    // console.log(response)
                    this.id = response.data.teams.id,
                    this.edit_team_name = response.data.teams.team_name
                    ...//some other data
                    this.edit_team_skills = response.data.teams.skills (//i want to pass here response.data.teams.skills.skills_name but it does not work)
                })
            },
```

and edit modal

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="team_name">Team Name</label>             
    <input v-model="edit_team_name" id="team_name" type="text" class="form-control"  >        
</div>        

<div class="form-group">  
    <label class="form-label select-label" for="team_foreman">Team Skill</label>
    <select v-model="edit_team_skills" class="form-select" id="team_foreman" >
        <option v-for="skill in skills" :value="skill.id" :key="skill.id">{{skill.skills_name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So when i click edit button i get `team_name` on `v-model="edit_team_name"` but i dont know how to keep selected also old value for `v-model="edit_team_skills"`

Comment: Shouldn't your select be be a multi select? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Basically I dont want to select multiple . But even  if i make select `multiple` how can i keep selcted value after i click edit button?

Comment: I mean the problem is i cant get old value for skills, witch i need to see on selected option like i see the team_name. If i want to edit a record i need to see old value of this record, but skills are with select option and also in relationships modal